# React Error: TypeError: Cannot destructure property

Tags: reactjs

I have this error « Error:  TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'id' of 'fetchedData' as it is undefined. » and I don’t know how to  deal with it

It’s a react app (port 3001) that use a micro API (port 3000).

```
import Data from "./Data";

export default class Service {

  /**
   * Fetch the user main data from the API
   * @param   {function}  resolve   the function for success
   * @param   {number}    id        the user ID
   * @return  {void}
   */
   getData = (resolve, id) => {
    fetch(`http://localhost:3000/user/${id}`)
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((result) => {
        const data = new Data();
     console.log(result)
        resolve(data.getData(result.data));
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log("Error: ", error);
      })
  };
}
```

the console log tell me « can not get user »

here is the Data class

```
export default class Data {
  /**
   * Service to handle the fetched data (user data)
   * @param   {object}  fetchedData   The data from the API
   * @return  {object}                The formatted data for the front
   */
  getData(fetchedData) {
    const { id, userInfos } = fetchedData;
    const { firstName, lastName, age } = userInfos;
    const userObj = new Infos(firstName, lastName, age);
    const userDataObj = new MainData(id, userObj);

    return userDataObj;
  }
}
```

I’ve no idea how to deal with this error and where is my mistake.

Comment: Are you sure the error message isn't complaining about destructuring `fetchedData`?

Comment: Yes, you're right, sorry. I edited my message. thx.

Comment: Then it looks like `result.data` is undefined when you pass it into `getData()`, and it's failing at `const { id, userInfos } = fetchedData` because fetchedData is now undefined.

Comment: Ok but when I put a valid id on the fetch path instead of $ {id}.
the console.log(result.data) give me the object I'm looking for.

Comment: The meaning of `${id}` inside backticks is not at all related to the destructuring `{ id } = whatever`, so I'm confused about your last comment.

Comment: If this is still broken for you, I suggest you create a codesandbox to demo the problem.  It's a lot easier to debug code when you can see it failing in real time.

Answer (score 1):

So I finally found a solution, the problem was to be able to retrieve the id inside the url and use it in the different child components that needed it.
It's not a very elegant solution but it worked.

```
/**
   * Fetch the user main data from the API
   * @param   {number}    id        the user ID
   * @param   {function}  resolve   the function for success
   * @param   {function}  reject    the fonction to handle error
   * @return  {void}
  */

  getData = (id) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      fetch(`http://localhost:3000/user/${id}`)
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((result) => {
        const data = new Data();
        resolve(data.getData(result.data));
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        reject(error);
      })
    }) 
  };
```

And how I use it in a child component

```
class Dashboard extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    const url = window.location.href.split("/");
    this.state = {
      id: url[url.length -1],
      keyData: {},
    };
    this.service = new Service();
    
    this.updateData = this.updateData.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.service.getData(
      this.state.id
    ).then(data=>{
      this.updateData(data)
    }).catch(error=>{
      console.log(error)
    })
  }
```